# Seeing Experience Editor markup instead of an editable field when using Sitecore JSS with React

Tags: jss

I'm trying to output an editable field in a component of my React-based Sitecore JSS application:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const AwesomeComponent = ({ fields }) => {
    return <div>{fields.title.editable} is awesome!</div>;
```

However when I add the component to a route and open it in the Experience Editor, I don't see an editable field, just some markup:

[image: Experience Editor markup]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For posterity it's worth noting that in later versions of JSS it's recommended to use the field rendering helper components, for example in this case:

```
import { Text } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-react';
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const AwesomeComponent = ({ fields }) => {
    return <div><Text field={fields.title} /> is awesome!</div>;
```

These handle the editable experience and encoding for you.

Answer (score 9):

For your own safety, React will automatically escape HTML in any rendered output. Since Sitecore provides its own markup for the Experience Editor, you need to use the [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) attribute to disable this behavior.

```
const AwesomeComponent = ({ fields }) => {
    return <div>
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: fields.title.editable}} /> is awesome!
    </div>;
```